# Kettle (Pentaho PDI): Couldn't find starting point in this job

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I'm manually creating a Job using Kettle from Java, but I get the error message `Couldn't find starting point in this job`.

```
KettleEnvironment.init();
JobMeta jobMeta = new JobMeta();
JobEntrySpecial start = new JobEntrySpecial("START", true, false);
start.setStart(true);
JobEntryCopy startEntry = new JobEntryCopy(start);
jobMeta.addJobEntry(startEntry);                    

JobEntryTrans jet1 = new JobEntryTrans("first");
Trans trans1 = jet1.getTrans();
jet1.setFileName("file.ktr");
JobEntryCopy jc1 = new JobEntryCopy(jet1);
jobMeta.addJobEntry(jc1);

jobMeta.addJobHop(new JobHopMeta(startEntry, jc1));
Job job = new Job(null, jobMeta);
job.setInteractive(true);
job.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that I was missing

```
job.setStartJobEntryCopy(startEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

Class org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta class has method findJobEntry

U can use it to look for entry point called "START

This is how it is original source of kettle-pdi

```
private JobMeta jobMeta;
....

// Where do we start?
jobEntryCopy startpoint;
....

if ( startJobEntryCopy == null ) {
        startpoint = jobMeta.findJobEntry( JobMeta.STRING_SPECIAL_START, 0, false );

// and then 
JobEntrySpecial jes = (JobEntrySpecial) startpoint.getEntry();
```